# How to get the type of stl container from object?

Tags: c++, stl

How to get the type of STL container from an object? For example, I have a `container` variable and I know that it is `std::vector<some type>`. I need to iterate the container using iterators. Is there a way to declare iterator without knowing the type of container?

I can get the type from the code of course, but I am curios to do it without using the type. Also I am not using C++11.

Comment: Can you show some code where you work with `std::vector` of "some type"s ?

Comment: Can you show some code that illustrates the problem you are having.  If you have a function that is accepting the `container` as a parameter, then the type has to be included -- unless it's a template, but even in that case you can use SFINAE to get what you need.

Comment: The compiler knows the type of the container, why don't you?

Comment: The `container` variable is a template parameter?  Is that why you don't know the specific type?

Comment: That's why `auto` is added to C++11 !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C++11 has some nice simple ways:

```
auto it = container.begin();
```

Or equivalently:

```
decltype(container.begin()) it = container.begin();
```

Or even:

```
decltype(container)::iterator it = container.begin();
```

Nonetheless, even if you can't use type deduction, you should never be in a situation where you couldn't type out the type in some form or another (perhaps involving template parameters). If the compiler knows what type it is, so do you.

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef std::vector<some_type> container;

for(container::const_iterator i = container.begin(); i != container.end(); ++i)
    // ...
```

You also have iterator typedef (that you can use instead of const_iterator). If you're using c++11 though, use auto, or the `for(auto& value: container) { ... }` form.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, but it's how the problem is typically solved.

Answer (score 1):

to get it from type:

```
container::value_type.
```

For associative containers; `container::mapped_type` (container::value_type corresponds to pair). It is according to Chapter 23 of C++ Standard.

use [boost::is_same](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_same.html) to compare types

to get it from object instance:

```
auto it = container.begin();
```

Comment: From an instance of the container.

Comment: ah, ok, I see, from object instance, OK

Answer (score 0):

One way is with a template:

```
template <class container>
void dosomething(container &c) { 
    typename container::iterator it = c.begin();
    typename container::iterator end = c.end();

    while (it != end) 
       dosomething_with(*it);
}
```

Depending on the situation, `auto` may be useful as well:

```
for (auto it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); ++it)
    dosomething_with(*it);
```

The latter requires C++11, but the former is available in C++98/03.